# How to rebuild Magento 1.3.2.4 corrupted database ready for migration to Magento 2.3.0

Tags: database, customer, migration, magento2.3, magento-1.3

We have an existing old live **Magento 1.3.2.4 website** (which is completely backed up).

We have built a new **Magento 2.3.0 website** which is ready to go live, but just needs the old Magento 1.3.2.4 data migrated into it.

> **Our first problem is the Magento 1.3.2.4 MySQL database was corrupted.**

We have created a new default Magento 1.3.2.4 website using a copy of the original database and successfully run the **Magento Database Repair Tool 1.2** as per the instructions.

The **Database Repair Tool** only found and **`fixed 2 errors`**:

```
Add missing foreign keys:

FK_CATEGORY_FLAT_CATEGORY_ID

FK_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_ID

to table "catalog_category_flat"
```

[image]

After the initial repairs, running the tool again found no errors.

However, the database is huge (**`about 280MB`**) and there are clearly more problems.

How can we clean up the **`database`**?

> **Our second problem is Magento admin ‘Customers/Manage Customers’ only displays 13 customers, but this should be about 1000 customers.**

All of the other missing customers and their data is still in the Magento store and visible when viewed via **‘Sales/Invoices’ and ‘Sales/Orders’**.

```
Magento admin displays 1054 ‘Sales/Invoices’

Magento admin displays 1081 ‘Sales/Orders’

Magento admin displays 1002 'Sales/Shipments'

Magento admin displays 48 'Sales/Credit Memos'

Magento admin displays 945 'Catalog/Manage Products'
```

How can we recreate all of the hidden customers?

> **Our third problem is how to export and migrate all the Magento 1.3.2.4 data into the new Magento 2.3.0?**

We need all of the data including the following:

```
Orders,  
Order addresses,   
Order payments,   
Payment transactions,   
Order status history,   
Quotes,   
Invoices,   
Invoice comments or Invoice items,   
Shipments,   
Shipment comments,   
Shipped items,   
Shipments tracking,   
Credit Memos,   
Credit Memo comments,   
Credit Memo items,   
Checkout fields,   
Products,   
Customers
```

How can we successfully migrate all of the data?